# std::enable_if ... else aka typename_if_else

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, enable-if

Similar to `std::enable_if` I would like to have an `else` type info (I need this for dependent variadic template `static_cast`). I extended the possible implementation from the [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Possible_implementation) as follows:

```cpp
template<bool B, class T = void, class F = void>
struct typename_if_else
{};

template<class T, class F>
struct typename_if_else<true, T, F>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<class T, class F>
struct typename_if_else<false, T, F>
{
    typedef F type;
};

template< bool B, class T = void >
using typename_if_else_t = typename typename_if_else<B,T>::type;
```

Is there a way to get rid of the empty struct (first definition) which is not needed any more?

Comment: You can get rid of all three specializations. Don't re-invent the wheel https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get rid of the empty struct (first definition) which is not needed any more?

Yes, thanks to [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) you can even get rid of the partial specializations:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<bool B, class T = void, class F = void>
using typename_if_else = std::conditional_t<B, T, F>; // (can be omitted if you only care for typename_if_else_t)

template<bool B, class T = void>
using typename_if_else_t = typename typename_if_else<B,T>::type;
```

Comment: Why not just recommending using `std::conditional_t` directly?

Comment: I didn't mean in the implementation of `typename_if_else`; I'm meaning why not entirely replace `typename_if_else`? It's just adding another layer of needless indirection to a functionality that already exists in the standard lib (and even uses the standard lib to implement this indirection)

Comment: @dfrib pfff that's what I get for answering an SO question while speaking on the phone... fixing thanks.

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for! Should be recommended in [_See also_ of `std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#See_also)...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a partial template specialization for `false`, and let `true` be the default.

```cpp
template<bool B, class T = void, class F = void>
struct typename_if_else
{
typedef T type;
};

template<class T, class F>
struct typename_if_else<false, T, F>
{
    typedef F type;
};

template< bool B, class T = void >
using typename_if_else_t = typename typename_if_else<B,T>::type;
```

Comment: This is partial specialization, not overriding